# Error 500 : ASP.NET core and angular do not find css file

Tags: asp.net, angular

I have a problem. I created an ASP.NET Core web application with Angular. Everything works but when I launch my projet I do not have CSS. In the console I have this error :

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500
>   (Internal Server Error)

So I searched in the server and I found :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[0]
>             An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request
>       System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Impossible
>   d'établir une connexion avec le serveur
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable1.GetResult()
>          at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.d__105.MoveNext()
>          --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable 1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>          at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.d__2.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.
>
> GetResult()
>          at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.d__59.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at
>
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.d__7.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
>       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>          at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>          at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>          at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack.ConditionalProxyMiddleware.

I do not know if the problem comes from this error
The declaration of the css, is done in the layout :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/dist/vendor.css" asp-append-version="true" />
```

I generated the project, I do not change something, all the file css are present. So I do not understand how can I change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pierre, your issues is related to the fact that every time you compile your angular app, ''/dist/ folder gets recreated. So, if you added manually 'vendors.css' file to that folder, VS would remember it, but angular compiler would delete it. If you use Angular-CLI, then the best way to handle all resources is to reference it in .angular-cli.json file:

```
"styles": [
    "vendors.css",
    "../Content/Layout.css",
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  ],
```

and you need to remove the reference from VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, I  found that the only way to solve it is to create a directory in wwwroot/dist/ and named it as externalRes and added the css file in it. then i call the file from shared/_Layout.cshtml
like this;

this was the only solution i did find.

> Code to happy